# Getting FATAL EXCEPTION in extended calendar

Tags: android, android-layout, calendarview

I was initially using the calendar view and that was fine.
i wanted to display my events in the calendar view so i tried extended calendar view library.

When i imported the library project and integrated the code i am getting the following error.

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class provider
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at com.ithoughtz.sns.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:171)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.provider
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    ... 19 more
```

Kindly let me know if i need to post code.

XML for calendar view as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <provider
        android:name="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.CalendarProvider"
        android:authorities="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.calendarprovider" />

    <com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your XML, please? :-)

Comment: Did you use different folder for xml? for example using one layout for portrait and some other for landscape.

Comment: I have posted the XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on project->Build path->configer Build path-> order and export-> checked all option->press OK...

Now try to run your project

Comment: we need a reason. OK?

Answer (score 1):

`provider` is a tag that has to be declared in the `AndroidManifast.xml` file of your project for declaring `ContentProviders` and not in the layout file.

`provider` is not an `xml` tag that is why your exception stack states the cause to be `provider class not found`.